# Rails how to set predefined attribute value for associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model like

```
class CqmExternalId < ActiveRecord::Base
        set_table_name :cqm_external_id
        has_many :ipp_measure_ids, :class_name => "CqmMeasureId", :foreign_key => "cqm_external_id", :conditions => [" name = 'IPP'"]
        has_many :numer_measure_ids, :class_name => "CqmMeasureId", :foreign_key => "cqm_external_id", :conditions => [" name = 'NUMER'"]
        has_many :denom_measure_ids, :class_name => "CqmMeasureId", :foreign_key => "cqm_external_id", :conditions => [" name = 'DENOM'"]
        has_many :denex_measure_ids, :class_name => "CqmMeasureId", :foreign_key => "cqm_external_id", :conditions => [" name = 'DENEX'"]
end

class CqmMeasureId < ActiveRecord::Base
        set_table_name :cqm_measure_id
        belongs_to :cqm_external, :class_name => "cqm_external", :foreign_key => "cqm_external_id"
end
```

How to make `ipp_measure_ids` association to insert default value on `create`

```
 c = CqmExternalId.first
 c.ipp_measure_ids.create!(:key=>"ABC-1234")  => #<CqmMeasureId id: 1, name:nil, key:"ABC-1234>"

 # I want the name attribute to be initialized automatically as "IPP"
```

Comment: Not sure about your question. which model you want to put the default value in which column.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh I want the `name` column of `CqmMeasureId` to have default values(on create) based on their association with `CqmExternalId`

Answer (score 1):

You can use before_save

```
class CqmMeasureId < ActiveRecord::Base
        set_table_name :cqm_measure_id
        belongs_to :cqm_external, :class_name => "cqm_external", :foreign_key => "cqm_external_id"

   before_save :add_default_name

   def add_default_name
     self.name = 'IPP' if self.name.blank?
   end
end
```

Comment: Thats a good idea but the problem is I'm using same model for all associations. So this  answer will set `IPP` for all other associations also

Comment: yes.. it is not the exact solution for your question. +1 for your thought.

Answer (score 1):

if you need through out your application for all the time then go for adding migration to set the default value to the column.

```
change_column :ipp_measure_ids, :name, :string, :default => 'IPP'
```

in this approach you need not have write ant thing automatically name column will be saved as 'IPP'

If there is any chance that in future you want to change the value in that case it is better to use a before save method in a model like

```
 before_save :save_default_name_value

   def save_default_name_value
     self.name = 'IPP' if self.name.blank?
   end
```

But make sure every time you save it (create, update) it will call this function. if you need only in the time of creating then go for `after_create` method.

Also check the http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
for more documentation.
Take a look on both the approaches and apply which is better for you.

Comment: Again, this answer works fine but I have multiple associations with same model. So this answer will set `IPP` for all  other associations also

Comment: No for multiple tables you need to set the default value for multiple table using migration or you need to write methods in multiple model.

Comment: if you are defining association to multiple model then method should be there for multiple model or else you can try using STI (single table inheritance). because by default every model is in inherited from ActiveRecord::Base but they are not in inheriting each other.

Answer (score -1):

Since all of your relations have the same class you're going to have write a wrapper method to perform this task on your `CqmExternalId` class. Something like:

```
def create_ipp_measure_id(attrs)
  data = attrs.merge({:name => "IPP"})
  ipp_measure_ids.create!(data)
end
```

And then use the method instead of `create!` on the relation.